# Can you convert STUDY codes to Pinescript indicator v5?

Tags: type-conversion, pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I had problems converting the following codes to v5. Specifically, I couldn't translate the "iff" command. Can you help please?

I wanted to combine two LazyBear 's indicators and turn them into one . I couldn't adapt it to v5 . I request your help in this matter.

Thanks.

```
study("RSI Bands ", shorttitle="RSIBANDS", overlay=true)

obLevel = input(70, title="RSI Overbought")
osLevel = input(30, title="RSI Oversold")
length = input(14, title="RSI Length")
src=close
ep = 2 * length - 1
auc = ema( max( src - src[1], 0 ), ep )
adc = ema( max( src[1] - src, 0 ), ep )
x1 = (length - 1) * ( adc * obLevel / (100-obLevel) - auc)
ub = iff( x1 >= 0, src + x1, src + x1 * (100-obLevel)/obLevel )
x2 = (length - 1) * ( adc * osLevel / (100-osLevel) - auc)
lb = iff( x2 >= 0, src + x2, src + x2 * (100-osLevel)/osLevel )

plot( ub, title="Resistance", color=red, linewidth=2)
plot( lb, title="Support", color=green, linewidth=2)


n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
 
ap = hlc3 
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = sma(wt1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need know is explained very well in this [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html).

[Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#removed-iff-and-offset) it explains the change regarding the `iff()`.

You just need to use the ternary operator instead.

```
// iff(<condition>, <return_when_true>, <return_when_false>)
// Valid in v4, not valid in v5
barColorIff = iff(close >= open, color.green, color.red)
// <condition> ? <return_when_true> : <return_when_false>
// Valid in v4 and v5
barColorTernary = close >= open ? color.green : color.red
```